# Apache Rewrite rule with multiple files from same virtual directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There are two parts to this problem:

1. I have used htaccess rewrite to change "file.php" to just "file" so http://www.example.com/file works just like http://www.example.com/file.php

Here is part of my .htaccess that deals with that:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule (.+) /$1.php [L]
```

1. The second part is the directory problem:

Here is part of my .htaccess that deals with the issue:

```
    RewriteRule ^register website/register

    RewriteRule ^register/rules website/rules
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

http://www.example.com/register uses the rewrite rule to show website/register
http://www.example.com/register/rules uses the rewrite rule to show website/rules

The problem is that the URL box shows example.com/register/rules but the page continues to show the content of example.com/register.

What is going wrong here? Is it the ".php" extension is the first part that is causing all this? Or is my htaccess just completely wrong?

Comment: Post the rules that are rewriting "file" to "file.php"

Comment: And is `/website/register` a real file or is it `/website/register.php`?

Comment: website is the folder where the file 'register(.php)' is located. It is referenced by example.com/register. Same with rules. website is the folder with the file 'rules' in it and it is SUPPOSED TO BE referenced example.com/register/rules. Basically 'register' file is supposed to act as a directory when i want to go to the 'rules' file.

Comment: So what's happening? Nothing? 404 error? 500 error?

Comment: Nothing is happening. The URL box shows http://www.example.com/register/rules but the page continues to show the content of example.com/register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nothing is happening. The URL box shows example.com/register/rules but the page continues to show the content of example.com/register

This is happening because you aren't bounding the rules, you have this:

```
RewriteRule ^register website/register

RewriteRule ^register/rules website/rules
```

The 2nd rule never gets applied because the URI `/register/rules`, matches the first rule's regex (`^register`, meaning, "the URI **starts** with `register`"). Either add ending boundaries:

```
RewriteRule ^register/?$ website/register [L]

RewriteRule ^register/rules/?$ website/rules [L]
```

or swap them around:

```
RewriteRule ^register/rules website/rules [L]

RewriteRule ^register website/register [L]
```

Though you will need the `[L]` flag.